# Replacing first, middle and last letter in a word on Java

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a big text with hundreds of O,o. Example:

String s = "Hello world, One!";

How can I replace letter `O`,`o` if it is first, last and middle letter in the word?

s.replace("o", "1");

I want: `Hell1, w2rld, 3ne` in all my text. Also I want to have possibility to select any other letter.

**The idear is how to select first, middle and last letter in a word?**

Comment: *I want: Hell1, w2rld, tw3* What do you mean? You want them returned in a list of strings? Or as one big string?

Comment: Use `StringBuilder` and it's `setCharAt` method

Answer (score 2):

There's a few ways I can think of doing it, each one would require a loop, as the value you are replacing with changes, something like...

```
String s = "Hello world, two!";
int count = 1;
while (s.contains("o")) {
    s = s.replaceFirst("o", Integer.toString(count));
    count++;
}
System.out.println(s);
```

or

```
String s = "Hello world, two!";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
int count = 1;
int index = -1;
while ((index = sb.indexOf("o")) != -1) {
    sb.replace(index, index + 1, Integer.toString(count));
    count++;
}
s = sb.toString();
System.out.println(s);
```

or you could use `String#split` and re-stitch the `String` back together, but it's a little more complicated

for example

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you an use regex engine or to be more precise methods from `Matcher` class:

- `appendReplace(StringBuffer sb, replacement)` - which adds to buffer `sb` text which exists until match is founded but instead of match will add value described in `replacement` parameter
- `appendTail(StringBuffer)` - adds to buffer rest of text after last match.

Demo:

```
String s = "Hello world, two!";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("o",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
int counter = 0;

while(m.find()){
    m.appendReplacement(sb, Integer.toString(++counter));
}
m.appendTail(sb);

String result = sb.toString();
System.out.println(result);
```

Output: `Hell1 w2rld, tw3!`

Comment: MadProgrammer, I wanted not to count letter:
Karla Jacint1 is sitting in a serene garden. She l23ks at the 4rdinary sights 5f

Comment: @Seomat I am not sure what your comment is suppose to be. If you wanted to address it to MadProgrammer then post it under his answer, not mine (currently only I was notified about your comment, MadProgrammer has no idea about its existence, unless he will visit this answer). Also if there is some problem with some answer then explain it. Post what example of input and expected result (possibly with logic explaining that result) and how result from answer doesn't match it.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "Hello world, two!";
String before = s;
int i = 1;
while (!(s = before.replaceFirst("o|O", Integer.toString(i++))).equals(before)) {
    before = s;
}
```

Comment: It's not that simple. OP wants to replace each o/O with 1,2,etc

Comment: Nikita Magonov, thanks for help, but your version does jnot work correct. Sorry!